# Nodejs : WebSocket doesn't seem to accept connections

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, websocket, openshift

I am hosting a simple server of node.js on Openshift but it does not seem to accept connections even though it is listening on the port. The code for my js file is as follows:

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

var players = [];

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var http = require('http');

console.log("ok");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      response.write("Welcome to Node.js on OpenShift!\n\n");
      response.write(ipaddress);
      response.write(port);
      response.end("Bye");
});

server.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    server: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: true
});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
  console.log("New connection");
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    ws.send("Received: " + message);
  });
  ws.send('Welcome!');
});

console.log("Listening to " + ipaddress + ":" + port + "...");

function player(id, x, y){
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

However, when I try to connect to this socket from an android emulator,I get not response. The code for the connection in android studio is as follows:

```
public void connectSocket(){
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://testapp-weihao.rhcloud.com:8080");
            socket.connect();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public void configSocketEvents(){
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Gdx.app.log("SocketIO", "Connected");
                player = new Starship(playerShip);
            }
        }
...
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you tried a simple send text client from the same machine where this ws server running : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#sending-and-receiving-text-data

Comment: Thanks but i've figured out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I've found the problem. Apparrently, for Openshift, the websocket listens on port 8080 but when connecting to it, the app has to connect to port 8000